# Disable Ctrl+D for particular workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> short cut for a particular workbook?
I can disable with Macro's but macros will affect all the excel workbooks.
I tried,

```
Sub diableCtrlD()
   Application.OnKey "^d", ""
End Sub
```

this is working fine only, but it's applying to all the workbooks.

I just want to disable to one particular document/workbook. How do I do that?

Comment: Why not use what you are using and in the workbook close/deactivate event, reset it? so if you go to another workbook, it shouldn't have that effect?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thanks for your quick response, but I will work simultaneously with multiple files, so I cant do that.

Comment: exactly my point, when you work on multiple files, the moment you leave the original file, the deactivate event will fire. Similarly you can use the activate event to disable ctrl D when the original workbook gets focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will make it so that when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it will check the workbook's name, it the workbook is `Book1` it won't do anything, otherwise it will do the default fill down event.

```
Sub Sample()
Application.OnKey "^d", "CheckWorkbook"
End Sub

Sub CheckWorkbook()
If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "Book1" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Selection.FillDown
End If
End Sub
```

Or

```
Sub Sample()
Application.OnKey "^d", "CheckWorkbook"
End Sub

Sub CheckWorkbook()
If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "Book1" Then
    Selection.FillDown
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: for this should I save the document as Macro enabled workbook?

Comment: Sorry dude, it's not working for me, short cut key is disabled in all workbooks :(

Comment: You'll have to show more data, as this is tested code. I opened 3 new workbooks, added this code to Book1 then testes, the Ctrl + D doesn't work in Book1, but works in book2 and Book3. tried and tested both options, are you sure you copied the code correctly and inserted it into a new module? and that you ran Sample first? As it is this code works, theres has to be something else preventing it.

Comment: How do we disable this feature itself. I have a workbook where I have some labels that are hidden away. When someone tries the Fill Down or Right, accidentally of course, the label gets copied over with formatting and everything. I understand how to disable to shortcut. The question is, how can I stop the user from clicking on the Fill Button from the Ribbon?