# Type mismatch on running VBA code on ctr (d)

Tags: excel, vba

[image: now i use ctr (d) in my sheet there are a error (Type mismatch (Error 13)) please give me a Solution thanks]

Now I use ctr (d) in my sheet there are a error (Type mismatch (Error 13)) please give me a Solution thanks

Comment: Paste codes as text rather than image then explain your problem in brief.

Comment: Show us your workbook data.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please also include which line exactly gives the  error. • Also do some research on how to turn off events before editing cells.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that changing the value of a cell on a sheet in the Change event for that sheet will trigger the Change event again. You should really turn off the event before attempting to make the change. As an aside I strongly recommend that you start to use indentation in your code to make it easier to read. Your code would look something like this

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target <> "" Then
            If Target.Offset(0, 27) = "" Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Offset(0, 30).Value = Now
                Target.Offset(0, 30).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works well if you only select a single cell and hit Ctrl-D, but if you select a range of cells then you will get the type mismatch error on line `If Target <> "" Then`
That is because a Range does not have a single value that you can test with = or <>

You have various options - e.g. only make this change if there is only one cell selected (e.g. by checking for `Target.Rows.Count < 2` and exiting the sub) or checking that the entire range is empty. I suspect that disabling Ctrl-D might be the better route - see [Disable Ctrl+D for particular workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408441/disable-ctrld-for-particular-workbook). How you deal with this problem depends on exactly what you are trying to do, and you haven't provided enough information to advise further

Answer (score -2):

`If Target <> ""`  here, you're comparing a "Range" object with a string. That's not possible. You want to try the Range's `Count` property and see if it returns 0 instead?

Comment: That's not correct. `Target` defaults to `Target.Value` if compared with a `String`. That is possiple to do. Just test with `If Range("A1") <> "" Then MsgBox "Not Empty"`. So `If Target <> ""` is exactly the same as `If Target.Value <> ""`. The issue is different: If `Target` returns more than one cell (eg. because copy and pasted a range) then, it still defaults to `Target.Value`, but this time this is no single value but an ***array of values***. And you cannot compare an array of values with a `String` without looping through the elements of that array.